How to configure Filebeat so that it send a complete entry from log
How I can configure Filebeat to send following message as one event? Our clients want to see such message as one contiguous entry in Kibana.
<get xmlns="http://services.example.com/">
     <request xmlns="">
        <credentials>
           <applicationUsername>******</applicationUsername>
           <applicationPassword>******</applicationPassword>
           <username>******</username>
        </credentials>
        <individual>
           <filter>
              <cqlQuery>*</cqlQuery>
              <startRow>0</startRow>
              <numRows>20</numRows>
           </filter>
           <payment getTransactions="false">
              <filter>
                 <cqlQuery>paymentid=123456</cqlQuery>
                 <startRow>0</startRow>
                 <numRows>100</numRows>
                 <mustHave>true</mustHave>
              </filter>
           </payment>
        </individual>
     </request>
  </get>


You can use filebeat multiline parser to combine multiple lines into one document.
Also check filebeat XML decode.
